# Am I the Jon Skeet of Meta?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues, mso-mse-split

If you looked at [the main Leagues page on StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/leagues), you might think so:

> [image]

Sadly, clicking through to the league page or my profile reveals that this is incorrect.

Comment: I'm curious how the process could have arbitrarily chosen me for three of the leagues while excluding those middle two.

Comment: Incidently the month and quarter are wrong too, just for a different user. [Lazy Ninja's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/209665/lazy-ninja) 137 rep doesn't quite cut it

Comment: This has been resolved.

Comment: You posted this question for the rep, didn't you? ;) +1